# Magento 2 : Pass a variable to getChildBlock() in LayeredNavigation view.phtml

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, layered-navigation, category-filter

I have to pass a variable in `layer/view.phtml`

> /Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml

to its getChildBlock which is `renderer/labels.phtml`

> Amasty_Shopby/templates/layer/filter/category/items/renderer/labels.phtml

I am not able to send a variable, have added a `setter` & `getter` in its block file.

Following the `layer/view.phtml`  file the block file I find is 
  `$block \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation`

I have overridden the vendor file with the following code

```
class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{

   private $_filter;

   public function setCustomVariable($filter){
   $this->_filter = $filter;
   }

   public function getCustomVariable(){
    return $this->_filter;
   }
 }
```

***I want something like that***

```
<div class="filter-options-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->setCustomVariable($customData)->render($filter); ?></div>
```

***and in the child HTML which is `layer/filter/category/items/renderer/labels.phtml`***

```
$block->getCustomVariable()
```

but it doesn't set the variable in `layer/view.phtml`  and not able to get the value in its child phtml `renderer/labels.phtml`

So upon digging I find the `catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml` in vendor which

> vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml

```
 <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

This say `Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml` has block file 
`Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category` which doesnt even exist in my code base of vendor.

`Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State` and `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer` is there in the vendor block folder but no `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category`.

[image]

At first, I have overridden the `Navigation.php` which is under `Block\Nagivation`.

Comment: You want to set value in $filter object?

Comment: No... a different variable... i just named the getter and setter that way as it was related to filter

Comment: @RohanHapani Edited

Comment: But, in $filter object you can pass array/Object which you want. Then, you want to add in custom function?

Comment: @RohanHapani  you mean in $filter object I can set my custom variable and retrieve it in the child phtml ?

Comment: Yes. You can.......

Comment: And how can I retrieve it in child html $block->getfilter() ?? And $filter object being set using render . What is this render .... If this would have been setFilter($filter) I would have easily user getFilter In child html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101004/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-summu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value in **$filter** object and access in your `labels.phtml`.

Add this code in your `layer/view.phtml` file :

```
<?= $filter->setData('custom_variable','custom_value');
<div class="filter-options-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->setCustomVariable($customData)->render($filter); ?></div>
```

Now, access in your `labels.phtml` :

> $filter->getCustomVariable();

or

> $block->getFilter()->getCustomVariable();

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: Can you tell me what does render($filter) function does on getChildBlock....

Comment: Just give me few minute.

Comment: Btw. Thanks @sumit. It's typo :D

Comment: @summu You can check here in this file : vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation/FilterRenderer.php